# semantic-release: is it possible to track and release a certain directory in a repo?

Tags: semantic-release

We have a Java project with a JavaScript submodule, the structure looks like this:

`java-project
 |- folder1
 |- folder2
 |- ...
 |- javascript-submodule
    |- package.json
    |- ...`

Is it possible to set up `semantic-release` to track changes to `javascript-submodule` only and trigger the npm release of it using `javascript-submodule/package.json`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **semantic-release** in any directory, you just have to make to `cd` in that directory before running the `semantic-release` command.

However the concept of **semantic-release** is to analyze commits pushed since the last release. It seems you have 2 different projects in the same repo (the Java one and the Javascript one) so the commit analysis would be problematic as **semantic-release** will also trigger releases for commit that make changes only in the Java project.
In addition **semantic-release** uses Git tags to identify commits associated with a release. So you will end up with tags like `v1.0.0`, `v1.1.0` etc... that are relevant only for the Javascript project and might conflict with the manual releases you do for the Java project.

Probably the best solution in your case would be to use **semantic-release** to release both project at once:
- Use the [@semantic-release/exec](https://github.com/semantic-release/exec) plugin release the Java project
- Use the [@semantic-release/npm](https://github.com/semantic-release/npm) plugin to release the Javascript project with the option `pkgRoot`

In such configuration both the Java and the Javascript project would be released together with the same version, and the Git tags would apply to both.